# background of svg image is damaged in flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, dart

I'm tring to use SVG image in Flutter
BUT the background looked like this
[image]

what is the reason why ?
the code is :

```
SvgPicture.asset(
  'assets/images/img.svg'
),
```

Comment: Inspect your browser which tag has this nice background, or if it is the svg, just looking at a picture without the svg makes it very hard of what is the cause

Comment: actually, it's svg format!

Comment: without a (stripped down) version of the svg it is hard to reproduce or investigate. replace the correct part of the svg (green) by a rectangle to slim it down, and try again or post the svg

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62869877/5362583