# How to Render SVGs in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg

Since the Analytics of Flutter svg is pretty low now, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#-analysis-tab- , what should be using to render SVGs in flutter.

Analytics:

[image: Analytics]

Why such scores?

[image: Why such scores?]

Answer (score 1):

Since, `flutter_svg` is every where, although I have found a work around for you and want to know how much beneficial it is for you. Flutter still doesn't fully support this `svg`, so need to find a work around.

Follow the below steps and see if that is workable:

1. Visit [Flutter Custom Icon Generator](https://www.fluttericon.com/)
2. Upload your SVG asset
3. Click on download button
4. You will get two kinda files:

   - iconname.dart
   - iconname.ttf font file
5. Use the file in your flutter package and import iconname.dart

Comment: Sure thing @Localhost. BTW - I like your name :-D

Comment: I can use the old version of flutter_svg as mentioned in the other answer, but I think this(answer) will be more memory friendly and will reduce the Apk size. But still this is not the replacement for svgs at all.I'll upvote the answer as it helped me thinking in different perspective, when I have upvoting privilege.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal, there are rules that the owner of the **package** must walk, and he may have forgotten about it in **flutter_svg 0.18.0** version.

Use this version **flutter_svg 0.17.4**, It works well

Pending problems are fixed